# Memory overload on for loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, ram

I am making an object spawn script in which on the start of the script the spawning function is called and in it is a for loop which creates an object each iteration. It first picks a random X position for it and then checks if it is in a range of another prefabs coordinates so they don't spawn too close or worse, one in each other. If it is in the same coordinates as another prefab it will return 0 and this same goes out for the Z axis too. It also picks a random Y axis rotation so it doesn't all face the same direction. After this it spawns the prefab and sets it's coordinates and rotation after which it check if the coordinates in the X or Z axis are 0, and if any of those two are 0 it goes back one iteration and the last object to be spawned is destroyed so it doesn't flood. This works perfectly but when you want to set it to spawn too much objects it floods the RAM because there is nowhere to spawn more objects. I tried finding the highest X position and highest Z position and multiplying them, and setting them both to positive, and then dividing them by the space between the prefabs but this doesn't work as it sets it to a really really high number. How would you fix this?
Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PrefabSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public int amountOfPrefabs;
    public int maxAmountOfPrefabs;

    private int currentSpawnedPrefab;

    public float spaceBetweenPrefabs;

    private float positionX;
    private float positionZ;
    private float maxPositionX;
    private float maxPositionZ;
    private float multipliedPosXZ;

    private bool previousSpawnHadZero;

    public GameObject prefab;

    private GameObject point1;
    private GameObject point2;
    private GameObject currentSpawn;

    private Vector2[] positions;

    void Start () {

        currentSpawnedPrefab = 0;
        previousSpawnHadZero = false;

        point1 = gameObject.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
        point2 = gameObject.transform.GetChild (1).gameObject;

        if (point1.transform.position.x > point2.transform.position.x)
            maxPositionX = point1.transform.position.x;
        else
            maxPositionX = point2.transform.position.x;
        if (point1.transform.position.z > point2.transform.position.z)
            maxPositionZ = point1.transform.position.z;
        else
            maxPositionZ = point2.transform.position.z;

        multipliedPosXZ = maxPositionX * maxPositionZ;
        if (multipliedPosXZ < 0)
            multipliedPosXZ += multipliedPosXZ + multipliedPosXZ;
        maxAmountOfPrefabs = Mathf.FloorToInt (multipliedPosXZ / spaceBetweenPrefabs);

        if (amountOfPrefabs > maxAmountOfPrefabs)
            amountOfPrefabs = maxAmountOfPrefabs;

        point1.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().enabled = false;
        point2.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().enabled = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().enabled = false;

        positions = new Vector2[amountOfPrefabs];
        SpawnPrefabs (amountOfPrefabs);
    }

    void SpawnPrefabs (int amount) {

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

            if(previousSpawnHadZero)
                i -= 1;

            currentSpawn = (GameObject)Instantiate (prefab);

            positionX = GetRandomPositionX ();
            positionZ = GetRandomPositionZ ();

            currentSpawn.transform.position = new Vector3 (positionX, this.transform.position.y + currentSpawn.transform.localScale.y, positionZ);

            currentSpawnedPrefab += 1;

            if (positionX == 0 || positionZ == 0) {
                previousSpawnHadZero = true;
                currentSpawnedPrefab -= 1;
                Destroy (currentSpawn);
            }
            if (positionX != 0 && positionZ != 0) {
                previousSpawnHadZero = false;
                positionX = 0;
                positionZ = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Pause () {

        yield return null;
    }

    float GetRandomPositionX () {

        //Finds a random position for the X axis and then checks it and returns either 0 if the position is taken or the position if not
    }

    float GetRandomPositionZ () {

        //Finds a random position for the Z axis and then checks it and returns either 0 if the position is taken or the position if not
    }

    bool CheckPositionAvailable (float pos, int axis) {

        //Checks if the position is available.
    }
}
```

Comment: You have just given us a wall of code here, can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Well mostly everything here is part of the problem but I'll try and remove some things

Comment: You really have to, nobody wants to debug all this code.

Comment: There, I removed as much as I could to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is really long to debug but the problem is clearly visible and is from the `SpawnPrefabs` function. Currently, when you instantiate a prefab, you check if the generated position is `0`. If `0`, you subtract `1` from the `i` in the `for` loop then destroy the instantiated object and then start the for loop again from the current loop-1.

So the combination of `Instantiate`, `Destroy` and repeating it over again in the `for` loop is causing the memory issue.

What to do:

You have to re-write the whole function and this will require modification in your whole code too. Do **not** instantiate and destroy object in that loop unless when needed.

**1**.In the `Start()` function, create **one** prefab.

**2**.Make it to be invisible in the scene by disabling its mesh/sprite renderer.

**3**.Use that prefab in the `for` loop to check if the generated position is valid. If it is valid, you can now create/instantiate an object in the loop.

This prevents instantiating and destroying objects in the loop when you only create objects when `if (positionX != 0 && positionZ != 0)` .